# Is there any way to revert changes from a specific file to the latest commit?

Tags: git

I just did add>commit>push and everything worked fine. Then made many changes and made some more pushes. But now one file is buggy and I need to revert only that file to the latest commit not the whole project. How can I do that without losing rest of my changes?

Comment: What do you mean by "without resetting head"?  What issue are you trying to avoid?

Comment: I just didn't want to use git reset head to remove the head.

Comment: `git reset --hard` (optionally combined with something like `git clean -xf`) is more or less the canonical way to get rid of uncommitted changes.  I guess I don't really understand the motivation behind not wanting to do this :/

Comment: @DragonKnight `git reset HEAD` does not remove anything from the commit history.

Comment: thanks for response. If not, what does these do? `git reset --hard abcdefg`  `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` and if I apply these commands, why I don't see my commit any more in reflog?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what `git reset` does. There are several ways to use this command. If you have made some changes and do not want to commit them, you can do `git rest --hard HEAD` to throw away all the changes. This does not change any of your existing commit history. It only changes the contents of the current working directory.

If you want to revert the local copy back to the latest commit but still save the changes you have made in order to reference them later, you can use `git stash`. Later `git stash pop` or `git stash apply` will restore the most recent stash.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me very well:

```
git status // showing all the files I changed after the commit.
```

as you can see in the log, it says: `(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)` so:

```
git checkout -- <filename as it shows in git status log>
```